# Why in the "have a nearly cycle" is grammatical?

Tags: grammar, exam-questions

This is a TOEFL question.

> Some animal activities, such as mating, migration, and hibernate have
>   a nearly cycle.

The solution says that "hibernate" is ungrammatical. By the way, I see that
because it's about the parallel structure and it should be "hibernation". But, I don't know why the word "nearly" is correct". It's an adverb not adjective :)

Thank you

Comment: Looks like someone typed *yearly* wrong.

Comment: It's possible :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo (***nearly*** = ***yearly***).

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know whether its wrong or not.I just wondered about my thought. It should be adjective not an adverb (near not nearly)

Comment: Switching from "nearly" to "near" _would_ make it grammatical, but it still wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'hibernate' is the incorrect word because it is not supporting the parallelism in the enumeration - ". . . such as **mating**, **migration**, and **hibernate** . . ."

mating and migration are nouns.

[to] hibernate is a verb.

The correct enumeration is, ". . . such as mating, migration, and **hibernation** . . ."

I think the word 'nearly' is merely a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Since *cycle* is a noun, and *yearly* modifies it, it's an adjective.

Words are adverbs if they modify modifiers or verbs.  While *-ly* is commonly used to turn a word into an adverb, if the word it is modifying is a noun, it's an adjective, regardless of how it is spelled.

Though I think the only common instances are *daily*, *monthly*, *weekly*, *yearly*.

Comment: If it's the word "yearly", "monthly", "weekly". It's OK. What I'm confused is the word "nearly". According to my question

Comment: I guess nobody came right out and said it: "nearly" is WRONG in that sentence;  "yearly" would make sense. We were kindly assuming the writer only slipped (a typo) rather than intentionally using the wrong word.